# How can I place 2 iframes next to each other?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need to create a page where I have 2 iframes next to each other with 100% height.

The left frame needs to have a fixed width of 140px and the right one needs to take the width of the rest of the screen. Keep in mind that both frames need to have 100% height.

Since there are different size screens I can't set a fixed with on the right iframe as I want it to take all the screen after the first 140px;

I kinds got it to work while using precentage. But the problem with percentage is the the left menu sometime show very wide

I created a fiddle to show you what I have done so far

http://jsfiddle.net/mwg3j17d/16/

```css
#main_block {
  display: block;
  width: 100% height: 100%;
}
#left_frame {
  width: 25%;
}
#right_frame {
  width: 75%;
}
#left_frame,
#right_frame {
  float: left;
}
iframe {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b_footer {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white: font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_block">
  <iframe id="left_frame" src=""></iframe>
  <iframe id="right_frame" src=""></iframe>
</div>

<div class="b_footer">
  Footer
</div>
```

As you can tell, there are couple of problems with my code.

1. The footer background's color for some reason is also showing where under the iframs.
2. The second problem is that I am using 25% width for the left iframe where it should be set to 140px
3. Finally, the height of the iframe is not taking the entire height of the screen.

How can I correct the problems mention above?

EDITED
I also tried to use Table to get the job done but the left iframe does not have the correct width. Here is an updated Fiddle to show you 
http://jsfiddle.net/mwg3j17d/19/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `width: calc(100% - 140px)` to create your right column.  Also, your `.b_footer` style was too large (10px padding + 100% + 10px padding) because you didn't specify `box-sizing: border-box`, so I added it.

1. Using float takes the elements out of the normal html flow, and has
   odd side effects if you don't fully understand them.  Use
   display:inline block instead.
2. Use `width: calc(100% - 140px)` to create your right column.
3. Use 100vh for the height instead of 100%;
4. You will have issues with the footer because again, 100% + whatever the footer size is always going to be larger than the page height.  Easiest solution is to fix the size of the footer, and use that in a height calculation.
5. I've added `html,body { margin:0; padding:0; }` to remove the margins and padding.  If you want them, add them back manually so that all browsers will use the same values, and use the new values in your width/height calcs.

```css
html,body { margin:0; padding: 0; }
#main_block {
  display: block; /* Useless, divs are display:block */
  width: 100%;    /* Useless, display:block elements are width:100% by default */
  height: 100%;   /* Fairly useless now, should take children's height */
  font-size:0;    /* Force space between inline-block elements to be 0 */
}
#left_frame {
  width: 140px;
}
#right_frame {
  width: calc(100% - 140px);
}
#left_frame,#right_frame {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
.b_footer {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_block">
  <iframe id="left_frame" src=""></iframe>
  <iframe id="right_frame" src=""></iframe>
</div>

<div class="b_footer">
  Footer
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, I was thinking along the same lines. Keep in mind that calc() is not cross-browser compatible as far as I know. You may need to add `width: -moz-calc(100% - 140px); width: -webkit-calc(100% - 140px); width: calc(100% - 140px);` Also, iFrames seem to ignore height: 100% for some reason. I'm trying to figure out a way to circumvent this.

Comment: @LaurensSwart Can use `height: 100vh`, but that only works if the page is always smaller than the viewport.

Comment: Thank you for this code. This fixed the width of the iframe which is problem 2 but still left me with problem 1 and 3

Comment: your updated code is closer. I created a fiddler with your code http://jsfiddle.net/mwg3j17d/20/ the only problem now is the the iframes are overlapping with the footer

Comment: @MikeA Change from using floats to display:inline-block so that they remain inside the normal html flow.  This will cause the container to actually have the correct height so that .b-footer acts normal.

Answer (score 2):

To display them next to eachother, there are several options, in this case, the easiest seems (to me, opinions differ), to add `float:left;` to both frames.

As for the problem with the frames not taking the full height, for this you can use `height:100vh` which means, 100% of the viewport height.

As for the footer being behind the iframes as well as under them this is fixed by forcing the footer to float at the bottom of the page at all times. This can be done by using `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` as well as `left:0`

As for the width having to be 140px, `calc(100vw-140px)` will do nicely here

**Your updated code**

**HTML**

```
<div id="main_block">
    <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" id="left_frame" src=""></iframe>
    <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" id="right_frame" src=""></iframe>

</div>
<div class="b_footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#main_block {
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#left_frame {
    width: 140px;
}
#right_frame {
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 140px); width: -webkit-calc(100% - 140px); width: calc(100% - 140px);
}
#left_frame,
#right_frame {
    float: left;
    height:100vh;
}
iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b_footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top:100vh;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgaLtbgg/2/)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like your solution, however: If you float the footer over the bottom part of the iframes, part of the scrollbars for both iframes will be hidden behind the footer, which can be kind of an issue. Maybe we can make the height of the iframes also `100% - 100px` for example?

Comment: If you check out the fiddle, the scrollbars are visible @LaurensSwart

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to have multiple iFrames that basically fill up the entire page, why don't you go with frameset?

```
<frameset rows="*,100">
  <frameset cols="140,*">
    <frame src="left.htm">
    <frame src="right.htm">
  </frameset>
  <frame src="footer.htm">
</frameset>
```

This circumvents all your problems at once.

Comment: Frame and frameset are deprecated and are being removed from current web standards, so they should not be used. See the MDN article here for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset

Comment: I'm aware of framesets being deprecated. I'm just trying to think out of the box here. Maybe this person only needs a simple solution for a small home-project (in stead of major production website) and then this could have saved him a lot of time.

Comment: That should definitely be a part of your answer!